# Nstimer count wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer, counter

I have a problem with NSTimer. I start and repeat it every 100ms and I have a counter to check if i runed 10s. The problem is it stoped in near 1 minute, not in 10s.
Here is my code

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)checkTimer
{

    timerCount += 1;

        if(timerCount == 1)
        {
                NSLog(@"start");
        }

        if(timerCount == 103)
        {
            NSLog(@"i got it");
        }
}
```

here is the log:

```
2012-11-19 08:57:42.063 Karagram[11708:540b] start
[Switching to process 8707 thread 0x2203]
2012-11-19 08:58:39.514 Karagram[11708:540b] i got it
```

I don't understand why it wrong. Somebody can tell me why? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is your app idle during this time or is it doing lots of other processing?

Comment: I'm streaming an audio and need to use timer to count when to stop streaming.

Comment: Was your app in the background at all during this time? Timers don't run if your app is in the background.

Comment: No, it still in the play screen.

Comment: Then why does the log output you posted show the process switch?

Comment: maybe it was streaming's process. i started timer when the streaming started.

Comment: If you NSLog, say, a dot every time `checkTimer` is fired, what do the timestamps on that output look like?

Comment: @Tommy I don't understand what you mean. But I think the problem is I running the process streaming an audio, so it made the timer delay. I created another project with only test timer, it work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSTimers aren't guaranteed to be accurate to within more than 100 ms or so.  [The NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) says:

> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the
>   run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able
>   to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various
>   input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of
>   the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100
>   milliseconds. If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or
>   while the run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the
>   timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer.
>   Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be
>   a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time.

By having it fire every 100ms you're compounding the error, because if it's off 50 ms every 100ms, by the time 10s has passed it could be quite far from what you expect.

If you're wanting to take some action after 10s, why not just set the timer to fire after 10s?

```
NSLog( @"start" );
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)checkTimer
{
    NSLog(@"i got it");
}
```

Also, are you doing your streaming on the main thread?  NSTimers work on the main runloop, so if you're blocking the main thread, timers aren't going to fire until it's unblocked.

Comment: Thanks @zpasternack. I test in 10s. But I really want it to work every 100ms. Because my application update every 100ms. I think the problem is I created streaming an audio process.While this process running, it made the timer delay.