# Is NSTimer impacted by processor speed, different generations of iPhones etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nstimer

I am implementing a countdown method in my game, which will use a 15 second countdown. I have been looking around for different ways of implementing this and believe NSTimer is the way to go.

However, someone told me that it can be impacted by processor speed etc. and my question is if this is true and if so, how do I counter for it?

I have seen this: [NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446766/nstimer-count-wrong) but dont fully understand the impact of this.

Is there any other way of guarantee 15 second downtime and all devices?

Comment: Have you looked at CADisplayLink class which is more efficient timer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: CADisplayLink is not appropriate for measuring wallclock time, since it's based on the refresh rate of the display.  That might be "about 60Hz", but it's not precise and in reality most LCDs are a little off any round number - e.g. 59.97Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your last sentence...

However, I believe your friends are right that it is slightly off compared to what actual seconds countdown to but I assure you that the difference is so small that it's not noticeable, especially for a game.

The reason for the difference is because you set an NSTimer to execute in one second, when it executes it updates the countdown on the screen then repeats. My guess is that NSTimer doesn't start to repeat until after it finishes executing your method so each NSTimer second is nano-fractions of a second longer than a real second.

Apple may be one step ahead of me and invokes the repeat before the execute, however, I'm not sure.

Either way, like I said, unless you're doing something major other than just updating the screen each second, your users shouldn't notice a difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer should be fine for most purposes.  It's not going to be exact - the period will be slightly longer than what you set, but in good conditions only by a very small amount - think milliseconds.  However, NSTimer fires via a runloop, so its accuracy is contingent on that runloop not being busy.  You can minimise issues by having a dedicated runloop, on its own thread, though you'll still see your timer's period expand slightly if the system is busy.

So while there's no innate relationship between CPU speed and other such factors, faster hardware will be able to keep up better by virtue of not being busy as often.

Note also that a repeating NSTimer will not phase shift - it'll be as accurate set to an interval of 1s as at 15s.  The only caveat is that if your handler is still running when the next fire should occur, that fire won't happen at all.  e.g. if you take 1.1 seconds, the gap between firings will jump up to 2s.

An alternative to runloops & NSTimers is dispatch_after.  It's not likely to be any more accurate though, and its skid is still contingent on the target queue (likely one of the default concurrent queues) not being busy when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

Theory: The `NSTimer` is not directly affected by the processor speed. A timer running for 1 minute on a Gen 2 device should also represent 1 minute on a much newer device.

Now that was the theory :), but in actuality, the processor speed not only affects your timers, but the general overall speed of your app (e.g., how fast your views change, how soon your music starts after you have pressed a button, etc). The only (or best test) is to repeatedly test your app on the types of devices that you are going to target. Test early, test often :)

You can not (based on my experiences) guarantee exactly time `T` on any device. You can however get times that are close on average to your expected time `T`.